# Spring nested transaction handling and nested propogation

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions, spring-annotations

I have a below scenario where I would like to understand the nested Transaction handling in Spring and also the propogation. I actually read enough about this but still was unclear about some facts.

```
public class ServiceImpl {
@Autowired 
public AnotherService anotherService;

@Transactional // by default it is PROPOGATION_REQUIRED
public void insert (){
    anotherService.anotherInsert();
}
}

public class AnotherServiceImpl {

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
public void anotherInsert() {
    insertSomeTestData();
}

private void insertSomeTestData() {
    // call insert some test data recursively
    // insert trasaction
    insertSomeTestData();
}
}
```

In this scenario, `anotherInsert` will commit the nested data and rollsback for some data , would this affect the outer transaction which is by Default `PROPOGATION_REQUIRED` Also the unclear point is still that , what If the transactions are nested, will they begin a new one in such cases?

Answer (score 2):

The "AnotherService.anotherInsert" call will create a nested logical transaction, under the already existing one from ServiceImpl.insert.

A rollback of the nested transaction will not rollback the primary one, like the REQUIRES_NEW behavior.

Specifications:

> PROPAGATION_NESTED uses a single physical transaction with multiple
>   savepoints that it can roll back to. Such partial rollbacks allow an
>   inner transaction scope to trigger a rollback for its scope, with the
>   outer transaction being able to continue the physical transaction
>   despite some operations having been rolled back. This setting is
>   typically mapped onto JDBC savepoints, so will only work with JDBC
>   resource transactions. See Spring’s DataSourceTransactionManager.

But, you should be aware that NESTED transactions are **based on JDBC savepoints** using a single physical transaction. This means that you must use a JDBC datasource and the following transaction manager to make it works :

> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager

Cf. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation-nested

Answer (score 1):

Here is the description for NESTED

"Execute within a nested transaction if a current transaction exists or it will behave like PROPAGATION_REQUIRED else"

In the mentioned scenario since there is one current transaction exists it will keep on executing under Nested transaction and will not create new one.

Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: The "AnotherService.anotherInsert" call will create a nested transaction, as an existing one already exists from ServiceImpl.insert.